# Alternative to "luit" which is available via homebrew

Tags: terminal, homebrew, encoding

I have a few legacy commands which I need to run in the terminal. Unfortunately they only work with ISO-8859-1 encoding being used.

For now I manually switch the terminal encoding, but that bugs me. On Linux I use luit, which can convert the in- and output from utf-8 to iso and vice versa (transparently for the run command).

Is there something similar for OS X, preferably available through homebrew or available as binary?

Greetings
-Sascha-

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can install XQuartz as a binary from http://xquartz.macosforge.org. It's the de facto standard X11 for OS X. It comes with `luit` and all the normal X11 stuff.

Homebrew does not have an X11 installer; it expects you tu use XQuartz, and will compile against it when it is present.

You could also use AppleScript to programmatically change your Terminal settings instead of doing it manually.

Answer (score 2):

I have `luit` on my Mac. It was installed as part of the X11 system from XFree86. I installed it via MacPorts. Perhaps Homebrew has an X11 installer too?